# Active directory authentication in php

Tags: php

I was trying to check authentication with Active Directory in php. I tried the below code but I am getting an error. I followed the link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php .

Code:

```
<?php

// using ldap bind
$ldaprdn  = 'Administrator';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = '****';  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap://dc1.example.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}

?>
```

Error :

> PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid
> credentials in /root/ldap1.php on line 14 LDAP bind failed...

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: Yes ,I have given the correct credentials  but still not working as expected . Is there any specific syntax for the username ?